# Getting notification from xcopy if file copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am generating a Windows Batch script to copy a file, only when the source is updated. If the file is updated, I want to delete another file.

The problem is that I can't find a simple way to trigger an event when the file update happens.

I thought of using `%ERRORLEVEL%` but this gives 0 whether file is copied or not.

I also thought of saving the xcopy output to a text file and then processing the file but this just seems to a little impractical for such a simple task?

Any other Ideas?

Code so far

```
SET SOURCEFILE=%CD%\source.txt
SET DELFILE=%CD%\toDelete.txt
SET DESTDIR=%WINDIR%\Deployment\ 

xcopy "%SOURCEFILE%" "%DESTDIR%" /c /d /q /y

REM IF File is updated, delete %DELFILE%
```

Comment: `for /F %%a in ('xcopy "%SOURCEFILE%" "%DESTDIR%" /c /d /q /y') do set "files=%%a"` and `if %files% gtr 0 echo File updated`

Comment: @Aacini Thats perfect. I have never quite understood FOR's in Batch but that works great. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explain the method used in command line posted by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) on entire batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SourceFile=source.txt"
set "DeleteFile=toDelete.txt"
set "DestinationDirectory=%SystemRoot%\Deployment\"

for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SourceFile%" "%DestinationDirectory%" /C /D /Q /Y 2^>nul') do set "CopiedFilesCount=%%I"

if %CopiedFilesCount% GTR 0 del "%DeleteFile%"

rem Add here more command lines using one of the 3 environment variables define above.
endlocal
```

First it is very important on copying a single file with **XCOPY** that the destination directory path ends with a backslash as otherwise **XCOPY** would prompt if the destination is a directory or a file.

**XCOPY** as used here always outputs to handle **STDOUT** as last line an information message with the number of files being copied at beginning even when nothing is copied or when an error occurred.

The command **FOR** executing **XCOPY** in a separate command process in background captures this output to handle **STDOUT** and processes it line by line.

Empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon are ignored with using the default options as used here with no `eol=` option. The other lines are processed with splitting each line up into strings separated by spaces or horizontal tabs on using default delimiters as used here because of no `delims=` option. Because of not using `tokens=` option just the first space/tab separated string of each line is assigned to loop variable `I` and the rest of the line is ignored.

The current value of the loop variable `I` is assigned on each processed line to environment variable `CopiedFilesCount` replacing its previous value.

The first space/tab separated string on last line output by **XCOPY** is the number of copied files which is here on copying just a single file either `0` or `1`. So finally after **FOR** loop execution finished the environment variable `CopiedFilesCount` has either `0` or `1` as value.

The value is compared with *GREATER THAN* operator of command **IF** to determine if the file was copied in which case the other file is deleted.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thats a great explanation Mofi, Thank you so much.